# Fragment ContestsFragment{3fa10a4} not attached to a context

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I have the following method -

```
public String getTitle() {
    int status = getArguments().getInt(ARGS_CONTESTS_STATUS);
    Context context = getContext();
    if (context != null) {
      switch (status) {
        case ContestUtil.VAL_STATUS_NOT_OPENED:
          return getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.ContestsFragment_Soon);
//        return "Soon";
        case ContestUtil.VAL_STATUS_RUNNING_BEGIN:
          return getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.ContestsFragment_Running);
//        return "Running";
        case ContestUtil.VAL_STATUS_ENDED:
          return getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.ContestsFragment_Winners);
//        return "Ended";
      }
    }
    return "null context";
  }
```

which always returns "null context".

My class is a fragment type which should return a context but for some reason the context is null when calling this method.

The only place where the method is being called is this class which extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter -

```
public class ContestsViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  private ArrayList<? extends Fragment> mFragments;


  public ContestsViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<? extends Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    mFragments = fragments;
  }



  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 3;
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return ((ContestsFragment) mFragments.get(position)).getTitle(); // <- here is the place where my method is being called 
    }

}
```

Comment: That might be because your context is null. Change Context context = getContext(); to Context context = getApplicationContext();

Comment: @Abhishek I do not have the following method for use

Comment: why are you doing this return "null context";??

Comment: @ShivamOberoi for debugging purpose only

Comment: This is not necessarily because the context is null. Maybe `status` doesn't match any of the cases you have.

Comment: @Fred so according to what you say I do not have any solution rather than to leave these strings hardcoded?

Comment: Not at all. I mean, I've tried to search for when `getPageTitle` is called to know if it was called after or before the context is attached - found nothing on this, but would be weird if the context wouldn't be attached. However what I'm saying is that if `status` doesn't match any of your cases, then you'll fall into returning "null context". Did you check the variable `status`?

Answer (score 0):

Call the getTitle function in onViewCreated